# redux with immtuable js

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to use redux with immutable js.
I made two reducers (layout, task) and it's working fine.

**layout.js**

```
const initialState = Map({
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
});
export default function layout(state = initialState,action){
  // Some Tasks
}
```

**task.js**

```
const initialState = Map({
  list: Map({
    tasks: List([]),
    status: 'INIT',
  })
});

export default function task(state = initialState,action){
 // Some Tasks
}
```

My problem is when i try to get state by mapStateToProps like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    task: state.get('task')
  }
}
```

it gives me an error 'state.get is not a function'.
when i changed it to

```
task: state.task
```

it works fine.

My thought is it's because combineReducers doesn't make immutable state.
Any solution for this? Or using `task: state.task` is the right way?

Comment: make sure you're using `combineReducers ` from `redux-immutable`. also, it's possible you are flushing redux store with some action to the mutable object.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `redux-immutable` library to make your store also an immutable object. By default it would return an `object`.
There are more details [here](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable#problem):

> When `createStore` is invoked with `initialState` that is an instance of `Immutable.Collection` further invocation of reducer will produce an error:
>
> "The initialState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of "Object". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "data""
>
> This is because Redux `combineReducers` treats state object as a plain JavaScript object.
>
> `combineReducers` created using redux-immutable uses Immutable.js API to iterate the state.

.